# Dimension of the quotient ring of a Noetherian local ring by a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noetherian, local-rings, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian local ring and $x\in \mathfrak{m}$. Then it is known that $\dim R/xR \geq \dim R-1$: [The dimension modulo a principal ideal in a Noetherian local ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085779/the-dimension-modulo-a-principal-ideal-in-a-noetherian-local-ring). If we add the additional assumptions on $x$ that $x\notin \mathfrak{m}^2$ and $x$ is not a zerodivisor in $R$, then is it true that the equality $\dim R/xR =\dim R-1$ holds?

Comment: Yes, see eg Lemma 13 in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00KD